# Why does the exponents of the prime factors of a perfect square have to be even?

Tags: prime-numbers, contest-math, prime-factorization

> Consider a set of $1985$ positive integers, not necessarily
> distinct, and none with prime factors bigger than $23$. Prove that there must exist four
> integers in this set whose product is equal to the fourth power of an integer.

For an integer $n$ in this given set we can express $n$ as $$n=2^{\alpha_1} 3^{\alpha_2}\dots 23^{\alpha_9}. $$

Now it seems that for another element $m$ in the set the product $n\cdot m$ is a perfect square if and only if the exponents of the prime factors of $n$ and $m$ are of the same parity? I don't really see where this is coming from. If they have the same parity then I know that the exponents of the primes of the product $n\cdot m$ will be even so my question can be reframed as

> Why does the exponents of the prime factors of a perfect square have to be even?

Comment: $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}\implies n^2=\prod p_i^{2a_i}$

Comment: @lulu see my answer.  where did $(1985)$ come from?

Comment: @user2661923 Not sure I am following your thinking.  A priori, there are $4^9=262144$ ways to set the exponents (assuming we only care about those $\pmod 4$).  Of course, many of the cases are unreachable.  $17^2=289$ so $17,19, 23$ can only appear to the powers $0$ or $1$.  $7,11,13$ can also appear as squares.  $5$ can be a cube.  Nor can we have $11\times 17$, and so on.

Comment: @user2661923  My guess is that the $185$ was to exclude $187=11\times 17$.  It isn't optimal...$185=5\times 37$ isn't an option anyway, so $184=2^3\times 23$ would yield the same sets.

Comment: @lulu You are right.  I confused $4^9$ and $4 \times 9$.  I have therefore deleted my answer.

Comment: @lulu as far as *unreachable*, here I don't follow you.  the max size of the $(1985)$ integers is unbounded, so $17^4$ is not excluded.

Comment: @user2661923  Ah, good point.  Tried to work the problem without my reading glasses.  Entirely misread it.

Comment: I think the pigeonhole principle is the key to solve this.

Comment: FWIW This is IMO 1985/4. Yes, PP is how this is solved.